# Updating two tables for generating invoice and activate user

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-3

I need to generate invoice at the time of activate user where `mobile_no` is in both table as foreign key.
I have two tables required update as follows

Table1 `CI_USER`

`is_active = 0/1`
   `mobile_no`

Table2 `VOUCHER`

`mobile_no` `voucher_no | Auto Increment` `voucher_date`

`voucher_amount` `reward1_amt` `reward2_amt`
   `is_reward1`

`is_reward2` `reward1_date` `reward2_date`

but i am facing some problem in function or controller so please provide me any solution for that

Model

```
public function edit_user($data, $id){
         $this->db->set($data);
         $this->db->where('ci_users.id', $id);
         $this->db->where( 'voucher.id', $id );       
         $this->db->update(array('ci_users as a', 'voucher as b'));
        return true;
    }
```

Controler

```
public function activate($id = 0)($mobile_no = mobile_no){
        if($this->input->post('submit')){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('voucher_amount', 'Voucher Amount', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'trim|required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $data['user'] = $this->Activate_member_model->get_user_by_id($id);
                $data['user_groups'] = $this->Activate_member_model->get_user_groups();
                $data['view'] = 'admin/Activate_member/member_edit';
                $this->load->view('layout', $data);
            }
            else{
                $data = array(
                    'mobile_no' => $this->session->userdata('mobile_no'),
                    'voucher_amount' => $this->input->post('voucher_amount'),
                    'is_active' => $this->input->post('status'),
                    'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d : h:m:s'),
                    'voucher_date' => date('Y-m-d : h:m:s'),
                    'voucher_no' => $this->input->post('voucher_no'),
                );
                $data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);
                $result = $this->Activate_member_model->edit_user($data, $id);
                if($result){
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'User has been updated successfully!');
                    redirect(base_url('admin/Activate_member'));
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            $data['user'] = $this->Activate_member_model->get_user_by_id($id);
            $data['user_groups'] = $this->Activate_member_model->get_user_groups();
            $data['view'] = 'admin/Activate_member/member_edit';
            $this->load->view('layout', $data);
        }
    }
```

Problem 1 of phrase on line no 1 of activate function
`Message: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ';' or '{'`
if calling 1 table like this working fine

```
public function activate($id = 0){
```

}

Problem 2 If going with only `($id = 0)
Messege :`'UPDATE Array SET `mobile_no` = '', `voucher_amount` = '11000', `is_active` = '1', `updated_at` = '2018-06-06 : 07:06:19', `voucher_date` = '2018-06-06 : 07:06:19', `voucher_no` = '' WHERE `ci_users`.`id` = '8' AND `voucher`.`id` = '8'`

Comment: your method should be like this : `public function activate($id = NULL, $mobile_no = NULL){
     ................
    }`

Comment: and for your second problem pass id and moblile_no as arguments in activate method